# Form submit onClick function not creating options in select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```js
 function getOption(){
    var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
    if(select.options.length > 0) {
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        alert("Text: " + option.text + "\nValue: " + option.value);
    } else {
        window.alert("Select box is empty");
    }
}

function addOption(){
    var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('New Element', '0', false, false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .pac-container {
            z-index: 10000 !important;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Shipping Method</h2>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Deliver To *</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select id="dynamic-select">
                            <option value="None">Select Shipping</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Delivery Address</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Add your Delivery Details</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                          <h3 class="panel-title">Address</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                         <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
                                            onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control">
                                            <br>
                                         <div id="address">
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="street_number">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Route</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="route">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">City</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control field" id="locality">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                                  <label class="control-label">State</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="postal_code">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="country">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <button type="submit" onclick="addOption()">Add NEW</button>
                                      </div>
                                        </div>            
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm new to Javascript and in this example, basically I have created a Shipping Method Page. In the "ADD Delivery Address" link, on clicking there is a address form which needs to be filled out and after pressing the ADD NEW button, all the address form data should appear in the select menu option like in the picture below. But I'm unable to do so. Can someone please enlighten me on his. It would be a immense help to me.I have tried numerous times, it works with a single field data, but with multiple fields it fails. Thank you

[image]

Comment: you mean to "address" "street" " city" like in dropdown?

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya yes exactly.........but i'm not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, your are using `button type="submit"` it is going to post back, Just use `<button onclick="addOption()">Add NEW</button>`

Secondly the `<form>` either you remove model from `<form>` tag or use `return false` in `addOption()` function

Third use jquery `map()` function to collect all fields value in side `addOption()`

Check this code :

```js
function getOption() {
    var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
    if (select.options.length > 0) {
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        alert("Text: " + option.text + "\nValue: " + option.value);
    } else {
        window.alert("Select box is empty");
    }
}

function addOption() {
    var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");

    var newListItem = $("#myModal input").map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get();
            

    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(newListItem, '0', false, false);

    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    return false;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Shipping Method</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Deliver To *
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">

                    <select id="dynamic-select">
                        <option value="None">Select Shipping</option>

                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Delivery Address</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Add your Delivery Details</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title">Address</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" class="form-control">
                                        <br>
                                        <div id="address">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="street_number">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Route</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="route">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="control-label">City</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control field" id="locality">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="control-label">State</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="postal_code">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="country">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="button" onclick="addOption()">Add NEW</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the new entered address in select :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for you kind support. this means a lot.

Answer (score 1):

first you created model popup add new button add submit so it submit form.
i have used for adding option into select something like.

```
var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
var option = document.createElement("option"); 
option.text = "your text";
option.value = "your value"
```

```js
function getOption(){
    var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
    if(select.options.length > 0) {
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        alert("Text: " + option.text + "\nValue: " + option.value);
    } else {
        window.alert("Select box is empty");
    }
}

function addOption(){
    var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    
    var data = getFormData();
    var text = data.address + data.street + " " + data.route + " " +data.city + " " +data.postcode
    option.text = text;
    option.value = "address" 
    select.add(option);
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
}

function getFormData(){
debugger;
var obj = new Object();
obj.address = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value; 
obj.street = document.getElementById("street_number").value;
obj.route =  document.getElementById("route").value;
obj.city =  document.getElementById("locality").value;
obj.state =  document.getElementById("administrative_area_level_1").value;
obj.postcode =  document.getElementById("postal_code").value;
return obj;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .pac-container {
            z-index: 10000 !important;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Shipping Method</h2>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Deliver To *</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select id="dynamic-select">
                            <option value="None">Select Shipping</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Delivery Address</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Add your Delivery Details</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                          <h3 class="panel-title">Address</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                         <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
                                            onFocus="" type="text" class="form-control">
                                            <br>
                                         <div id="address">
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="street_number">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Route</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="route">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">City</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control field" id="locality">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                                  <label class="control-label">State</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="postal_code">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="country">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <button type="button" onclick="addOption()">Add NEW</button>
                                      </div>
                                        </div>            
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept in a precise way. :-)